# Cannot put title to the top of Pie chart in R

Tags: r, charts, pie-chart

I am using a custom function to make a pie chart and depending on the condition, i plot a single pie or two pies chart. The condition where i have two rows in the input file, which corresponds to two pies works great but when the input file is a single row which correspond to single pie, then i having trouble adjusting the font sizes of legend and adding title to the top of that plot. Here is my function

```
pie_plot<-function(mean.IU,isoforms,gene.name,output.file,group,output.screen){
  n.isoform<-length(isoforms)
  color.pie<-as.vector(t(sapply(seq(1,0.1,length.out=n.isoform/5),function(i)rainbow(5,s=i))))

  if (nrow(mean.IU)==2){
    pdf(output.file,width=15)

    par(mar=c(0,0,0,0),oma=c(0,0,10,0),bg="seashell")
    layout(matrix(1:3,nrow=1),widths=c(2,1,2))
    pie(mean.IU[1,],col=color.pie,labels=ifelse(round(mean.IU[1,],3)<0.005,NA,paste(round(mean.IU[1,],3)*100,"%",sep="")),cex=max(0.4,1.71-0.121*sqrt(n.isoform)),radius=0.8)
    mtext(group[1],cex=2)
    plot.new()
    legend("center",legend=isoforms,title="Isoform",fill=color.pie,bty="n",cex=max(0.25,3.0-sqrt(n.isoform)*0.25),ncol=1)
    pie(mean.IU[2,],col=color.pie,labels=ifelse(round(mean.IU[2,],3)<0.005,NA,paste(round(mean.IU[2,],3)*100,"%",sep="")),cex=max(0.4,1.71-0.121*sqrt(n.isoform)),radius=0.8)
    mtext(group[2],cex=2)
    mtext(paste("Pie charts for gene ",gene.name,sep=""),outer=TRUE,cex=2.5,line=5,font=2)

    dev.off()
  }
  else{
    pdf(output.file,width=15)

    par(mar=c(0,0,0,0),oma=c(0,0,5,0),bg="seashell")
    layout(matrix(1:2,nrow=1),widths=c(7,3))
    pie(mean.IU[1,],col=color.pie,labels=ifelse(round(mean.IU[1,],3)<0.005,NA,paste(round(mean.IU[1,],3)*100,"%",sep="")),cex=max(0.4,1.71-0.121*sqrt(n.isoform)),radius=0.8)
    mtext(group[1],cex=2)
    plot.new()
    legend("center",legend=isoforms,title="Isoform",fill=color.pie,bty="n",cex=max(0.1,3.0-sqrt(n.isoform)*0.20),ncol= 1)
    mtext(paste("Pie chart for gene ",gene.name,sep=""),outer=TRUE,cex=2.5,line=5,font=2)
    dev.off()      
  }
}
```

Where am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that there are problems with plot margins and when i changed it for the 2nd condition, everything worked great.

I have changed from `par(mar=c(0,0,0,0),oma=c(0,0,5,0),bg="seashell")` to `par(mar=c(0,0,0,0),oma=c(0,0,10,0),bg="seashell")`.